# lambda python to run shell script

Tags: python, bash, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I'm trying to execute an existing shell script from a python based lambda. The shell script uses `aws cli` commands to build a set of machines and services. I am trying to use python to add some logic before/after the script run. Although it looks like with time I could re-configure most the shell script to use boto3. I was hoping that while I could get a ugly solution going where the python runs the checks I need and reuses the existing script.

Is there a way to have python execute the `.sh` file from S3?

Tired the following in a few variations:

```
import subprocess
action=subprocess.call(['aws s3 cp S3:/bucket/path/file.sh - | bash'])
```

Running each `aws cli` command in separate subprocesses line also does not work as there is a lot of ' reuse which kills causing confusion/errors in python.

Comment: you *might* be able to run boto3 `s3.get_object()` to stream the file into subprocess.call but I am not even sure you can run a bash script in a Lambda - its images are pretty stripped down so if it even has bash available to the execution would be pretty incredible.  id be curious if you get it to work though, to increase my knowledge  of lambda backend

Comment: tho your use case fits more with a Codebuild than a lambda - and in codebuild you very much CAN run bash scripts. Since you seem to be trying to work out a way to deploy, you should also look into CDK and/or Cloudformation to do that for you (as thats what those services are designed to do)

Comment: have you given the thought of using the lambda with custom container image.

Comment: @lynkfox, very insightful. I'm hoping to move to Codebuild, CF, or CDK soon (being a relative term).  I was hoping to get this item off running before pulling in a new service. will check the `s3.get_object()`

Comment: Honestly, a codebuild is super simple. It is simply a Source (Github, CodeCommit, a zip archive in an s3) and a Buildspec - and the buildspec is just a set of phases with a list of commands after them - the commands are just straight shell commands because the Codebuild is a temporary EC2 instance that is spun up for build then decommed.  It will take you probably less than an hour to get it up and going, where as the hack you are trying to pull off may leave you stranded for days.

Comment: @lynkfox, as you indicated the bash script isn't supported due to the stiped down lambda machines. Found aws docs saying as much and offering lambda layers as their workaround. I think the answer is move to codebuild.
Thank you for your comments.

Comment: thanks for the updates! good luck!